# drawing 3d shapes in line-strip mode

Tags: opengl, glut

I want to draw some 3d shape with line-strip mode.

I can't figure out how the coordinate system works. whatever coordinates I place I only get a straight line...

I want to use this function

```
void drawLineStrip(){
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    glVertex3f(? ,?,?);  // V0
    glVertex3f(?,?,? );  // V1
    glVertex3f(?,?,?) ;  // V1
            .......
            .......


    glEnd();
```

}

1.could anyone explain me how the coordinate system works ?

2.does anyone has an example of some drawing with this mode (line strip) which is not a straight line and look like 3d?

Comment: What coordinates did you try? (0,0,0), (10,10,10), (100,100,100), for example, would draw a straight line -- which is correct.

Comment: I was just testing on different numbers. for ex:   glVertex3f(0,0,0);  
  glVertex3f(2,1.5,10) );  
  glVertex3f(3,.8,10) ;  
  glVertex3f(-6,1.5,10)  ;

Comment: You are going to need to show the matrices you are using for projection and modelview in order to explain the coordinate system to you. If you have not set any up, then your entire range of coordinates is [-1.0, 1.0] in all directions.

Comment: I have just started using open GL so I am not sure what you are talking about .... so by default the width of the screen is between -1 to 1 from all the sizes?

Comment: @Shiran: By default, the point (-1,-1,-1) is the *closest (depth)* point to you at the bottom-left corner of your ***viewport***, (1,1,1) is the *farthest (depth)* point from you at top-right. Any point outside that range is outside of your view. This is the coordinate space that GL naturally works with, but the modelview and projection matrices are designed to allow you to define your own coordinate space. You should [read up on coordinate transformations](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html) if you want to better understand this.